# how to define phone types (home, office, work) using schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

How could I define Phone Types by using Schema.org ?

example, I would like to have this in Json-ld:

```
    "phones" : [
    {
        "type" : "office",
        "number" : "123456789"
    },
    {
        "type" : "work",
        "number" : "123456789"
    }
    ]
```

is there a way to use schema.org as context to define these ? I looked in FOAF or goodRelations, but they all use only one telephone : http://schema.org/telephone

Comment: you can do this very easily using microformats, which schema.org uses too....if you care, i'll show you how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use [contactPoint](http://schema.org/contactPoint) instead of the `telephone` property. So, your JSON-LD document would look something like this:

```
"contactPoint" : [
  {
    "contactType" : "office",
    "telephone" : "123456789"
  },
  {
    "contactType" : "work",
    "telephone" : "123456789"
  }
]
```

Please note that you can change your JSON-LD context to get the JSON in the shape you want. For example:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "http://schema.org",
    {
      "phones": "http://schema.org/contactPoint",
      "type": "http://schema.org/contactType",
      "number": "http://schema.org/telephone"
    }
  ],
  "phones" : [
    {
      "type" : "office",
      "number" : "123456789"
    },
    {
      "type" : "work",
      "number" : "123456789"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To go a step further is there a way to define the specification of type. like it is constrained to be office or work, or home. In other words an enum. Is it possible to express an enum in json-ld?

Comment: Schema.org defines the value of contactType to be a string and doesn't restrict it any further: http://schema.org/contactType. Google is a bit more explicit on what *they* understand in the context of organizations: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4620709?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If not needed for `Place`, you could use `contactPoint`→`ContactPoint`, [as suggested by Markus Lanthaler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25268622/1591669).

Alternatively, you could [extend](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) the [`telephone` property](http://schema.org/telephone), e.g. by using

- `telephone/office`
- `telephone/work`

But this is not a good solution if you expect other consumers to understand and make use of your data. (And it’s [probably "outdated"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185362/1591669), too.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is correct, this Google page specifies how to differentiate between 'ContactType's:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4620709?hl=en

The page provides a number of examples.

Comment: Link-only answers are considered low quality, can you please include the actual solution in your post?