# extending html5 microdata event schema

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup, microdata

Have been adding html5 microdata to my online resume, and read in http://www.schema.org/docs/extension.html that you can extend existing schema.

I've been trying to extend Event to describe a Job with the following markup:

```
        <div class="job" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event/Job">
            <h2 itemprop="name">Web Developer</h2>
            <div itemprop="organizer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
                <span itemprop="name">Company Name 2</span>
                <span itemprop="location">London</span>
            </div>
            <span itemprop="startDate">January 2000</span>
            <span itemprop="endDate">February 2009</span>
            <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</p>
        </div>
```

When i use the Google Structured Data Testing Tool it gives the following errors:

```
        Item
            type:   http://schema.org/event/job
            property:
              name:         Web Developer
              organizer:    Item 4
              start date:   January 2000
              enddate:      February 2009
              description:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
        Error: Page contains property "name" which is not part of the schema.
        Error: Page contains property "organizer" which is not part of the schema.
        Error: Page contains property "startdate" which is not part of the schema.
        Error: Page contains property "enddate" which is not part of the schema.
        Error: Page contains property "description" which is not part of the schema.
        Error: Missing required field "dtstart".
        Error: Missing required field "name".
```

Any ideas what's wrong? and how it should be done?

Many thanks,!

Comment: There is now an [open issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/603) for creating resume/employment history. 

Past jobs are not really 'events', it might be better to use the Person schema with employeeof and Organization inside it.  The http://schema.org/Role schema gives a start/end date and job desciption so could be used too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google’s tool is wrong about the errors, probably because they don’t handle the case of Schema.org extensions (which is a valid use of the vocabulary).

But note that this extension mechanism is considered "outdated" anyway, see [docs/extension.html is out of date, should be marked as such or fixed](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/164). It’s intended to display this message on the extension page soon:

> **Historical ("Slash-based") Extension Mechanism (2011-2013)**
>
> Status Note: We preserve this text to document our original approach to extensibility. We do not currently advocate the use of '/'-based extended names, although it should be harmless to use these. Other mechanisms including RDFa, JSON-LD, the `Role` type and `additionalType` property can now also be used for different extension scenarios.
>
> […]

(By the way, your values of `startDate` and `endDate` are not valid: you need to use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your new schema specification needs to be hosted somewhere. The errors probably show because `http://schema.org/Event/Job` doesn't exist.

You could try augmenting the schema.org `Event` with properties from another vocabulary as explained [here](http://richard.cyganiak.de/2011/10/microdata.html).