# How to do a new extension with Schema.org + Microdata?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have seen in a post that the slash is no longer up to date for creating new extensions in Schema.org.

I am using Microdata and would prefer to stick to it across my site.

What is the new way to create a new extension?

For example I want to create a new extension for `MedicalTourism` under the category [`Travel Agency`](http://schema.org/TravelAgency). Before it would have been

```
http://schema.org/TravelAgency/MedicalTourism
```

What is the new way?

And what would the code look like?

Comment: HI Unor Could you please help me answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206514/blogger-schema-org-blogposting-properties-in-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *may* still use Schema.org’s ["slash-based" extension mechanism](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html). It’s ["outdated"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185362/1591669), but not invalid.

But it’s not (and never was) a good idea to use this mechanism if you want other consumers to understand or make special use of your extensions.

In some cases you could use Schema.org’s [`Role` type](http://schema.org/Role), which allows you to give some additional data about a property, but not about types.

#### Alternatives

- [Propose new types/properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581768/1591669): If they are useful and the sponsors agree, they might get added to the Schema.org vocabulary at some point.
- Use an [existing vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) that defines types/properties for your use case (or [create a new vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21162395/1591669) if you don’t find one):

  - Either instead of Schema.org,
  - or in addition to Schema.org (while this works nicely with RDFa, Microdata is pretty [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669): you’d have to use Schema.org’s [`additionalType` property](http://schema.org/additionalType) for additional types and full URIs for additional properties).

Comment: HI Unor I have resolved the question by using a lower category. For example for a plastic surgery procedure like Liposuction I use the category https://schema.org/PlasticSurgery and then add the relevant properties: name, description, image, offer, price, etc... I skip the use of Travel Agencycompletely as it is not directly relevant to the page for liposuction even though it is a medical tourism product offered by a travel agency.