# Blogger: Schema.org BlogPosting properties in template

Tags: html, blogger, schema.org

Google Testing Tool gives me an error message for the Blogposting properties that are in the default Blogger template code.

```
<div class='post hentry' itemprop='blogPost' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
<meta content='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ueq2DH-BE-w/VRERR_6UQ3I/AAAAAAAAHB8/W9hPxVqDOtM/s1600/DNT.jpg' itemprop='image_url'/>
<meta content='xxxxx' itemprop='blogId'/>
<meta content='xxxxx' itemprop='postId'/>
<a name='xxxxxx'></a>
```

It says that it does not recognise these properties as part of http://schema.org/BlogPosting:

1. image_url
2. blogId
3. postId

Should I ignore this error message?

Or should I delete this part of the microdata code from the blogger template?

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Comment: HI Alex I have added the code from the Blogger template. Google Testing does not say that there is a problem with the code. It says that it does not recognise blogId and postId as properties of BlogPosting. I checked in Schema.org. Neither blogId nor postId are listed properties under https://schema.org/BlogPosting

Comment: *Structured Data Testing Tool* error message: The property `blogPost` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Article`

Answer (score 3):

I have read your post and I can help you just do following things:

**(1). Fixing blog & post id error:**

Find below piece of codes in your template and delete them:

`<meta expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId'/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postId'/>`

**(2). Fixing image_url:**

Find below code in your template:

```
<meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' itemprop='image_url'/>
```

And replace it with `<meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' itemprop='image'/>`

Source link: http://101helper.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-fix-google-webmaster-tools-errors.html

You may find more errors like Headline,updated,author,datepublished. You can fixing them by visiting this link http://101helper.blogspot.com/2015/08/fixing-headline-and-datepublished-blogger.html`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters the same issue, here is an article I found that exactly fixed all of my blog errors:
https://amprandom.blogspot.tw/2016/09/how-to-fix-structured-data-errors-in.html