# Is it possible to add custom attributes in Microdata?

Tags: microdata

Is there an option to add custom attributes to a scheme? (same as we can expand DTD?)

`itemprop="description"` isn't enough for me. I got more attributes that I wish to add, that do not exist in the original scheme:

- Objective
- Duration
- Availability

I need this attributes cause they project the full characteristic of my product.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Schema.org: How to extend a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581209/schema-org-how-to-extend-a-class)

Comment: Which does not have a satisfactory answer... It basically says 'just don't extend but use these existing properties'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microdata, you can use a "[proprietary item property name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute)":

> one used by the author for private purposes, not defined in a public specification

It has to be an absolute URL, e.g.:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <p itemprop="description">…</p>
  <p itemprop="http://example.com/voc/objective">…</p>
</div>
```

(Of course you can’t expect other consumers to make use of it.)

If you are using the Schema.org vocabulary, you could also:

- [propose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581768/1591669) new Schema.org properties/types
- [extend](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) an existing Schema.org property (but it’s [considered outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185362/1591669))